# DD-WRT: Repeater bridge with VPN?

Tags: vpn, dd-wrt, openvpn, bridge, repeater

Setup:

- Router1 and Router2 run DD-WRT
- Cable modem is connected to WLAN port of Router1
- Router2 runs in Repeater Bridge mode (there is also a separate SSID with virtual interface)

This setup works great! All devices can see each other and can see the internet.

Now I want to make it so that all traffic through Router2 is routed through a 3rd party VPN connection (AirVPN). The problem is that Router2 no longer shows VPN options. I really wanted to be able to do VPN while in Repeater Bridge mode because it means I can connect to the "unique" SSID on Router2.

If I was to put Router2 in to "Repeater" mode then apparently both Routers operate on different subnets and hence my TV (on Router1) won't be able to see my server (on Router2).

I need solutions! Please help.

Comment: I've just experimented with Repeater mode. Server: 192.168.2.145 and TV: 192.168.1.103. The server can ping the TV but the TV cannot ping the server.

Comment: It seems there's no VPN options under Repeater mode